# Does a git remote repo knows who pulled what at what time?

Tags: git

I am wondering what information on pull and fetch activities git safes on the side of a repo from which is pulled (so on the side of a remote repo from my point of view). Unfortunately I did not find the answer after reasonably long browsing the internet.

Comment: Git on its own doesn't log any activities on a remote repo. I run a private git server with gitolite which has the option to log who has accessed which repo and if it was an push or a pull/fetch.

Comment: What version of git are you running on the server?  How are you running it?  Is it running within the context of a hosting provider (eg, GitHub Enterprise, Team Foundation Server)?  Or are just just running `git` over HTTP or SSH?